# Buscar registros por criterio no muestra nada

Tags: php, mysql

Hago esta consulta en PHP/MySQL y quiero que los registros estén ordenados por el campo **nom** Pero no muestra nada.

```
$stm = $BD->prepare("SELECT a.cod, a.nom, b.id_pago, c.planilla
FROM sc_personal a,
sc_condicion b,
sc_planilla c
WHERE  a.id_condicion = b.id_condicion
AND  a.id_trab = c.id_trab
AND  a.cod ='.$valor'. ORDER BY a.nom ASC");
```

Antes terminaba en:

```
AND  a.cod =".$valor);
```

Y no había problema, ahora le agregué el ORDER BY y no muestra nada.
Cuál es el problema?

Comment: Estas concatenando mal, pero la pregunta es ¿Por que concatenas valores si estas utilizando sentencias preparadas?

Comment: La respuesta de @Xerif enfoca muy bien el problema , aunque también yo haría mi consulta usando `JOIN`... así el código es más fácil de entender y mantener.

Comment: Cierto @A.Cedano no me fije en la consulta sinceramente, pero bien visto.

Comment: @A.Cedano Usando Join sería más eficiente?

Comment: @Piropeator  **[yo plantee esa duda hace un tiempo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/74498/29967)** y al parecer no hay diferencia en el rendimiento. De todos modos, creo que con `JOIN` el código queda más fácil de entender.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No deberías concatenar valores en las sentencias preparadas. Los valores deberían ser ligados. Ademas tienes un error concatenando.

Ejemplo de como podría quedar:

```
$stm = $BD->prepare("SELECT a.cod, a.nom, b.id_pago, c.planilla
FROM sc_personal a,
sc_condicion b,
sc_planilla c
WHERE  a.id_condicion = b.id_condicion
AND  a.id_trab = c.id_trab
AND  a.cod = ? ORDER BY a.nom ASC");

// Ligamos el valor
$stmt->bind_param('s', $valor);
// Ejecutamos
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Estás concatenando mal, intenta de esta forma:

```
$stm = $BD->prepare("SELECT a.cod, a.nom, b.id_pago, c.planilla
                     FROM sc_personal a,
                          sc_condicion b,
                          sc_planilla c
                     WHERE  a.id_condicion = b.id_condicion
                     AND  a.id_trab = c.id_trab
                     AND  a.cod ='" . $valor . "' ORDER BY a.nom ASC");
```