# Quisiera realizar un promedio de una columna bajo condiciones de otras dos diferentes de la misma tabla en postgresl

Tags: postgresql, postgis

¡Hola! Soy estudiante de geografia y (muy) nuevo en el mundo de SQL, actualmente uso Postgresql y quiero hacer una consulta algo compleja. Hay varios campos de maíz (columna "campo") que fueron sembrados con diferentes tipos de semillas (columna "semilla" que contiene tipo 1, tipo 2, tipo 3) a su vez otra columna "fecha" contiene año mes y día de la siembra (hay 10 fechas diferentes) y finalmente una columna con el rendimiento de esa fila (min.0 max. 100). ¿Cómo podría proceder a promediar el rendimiento de cada tipo de semilla a lo largo del tiempo? de forma que quede el promedio de cada tipo de semilla sea dividido en las (10) fechas de siembra. Mi idea es crear un gráfico X e Y con los valores rendimiento (y) y tiempo (x) en cada campo. ¡Gracias!

Comment: queres obtener el promedio del rendimiento de cada tipo de semilla en cada fecha de siembra?

Comment: Te recomiendo agregar un ejemplo de la tabla y un ejemplo del resultado esperado. Y el mejor de los casos un SQLFiddle. Aquí un ejemplo de pregunta de SQL https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/74498/unir-tablas-con-join-o-con-where-en-sql-cu%c3%a1l-es-m%c3%a1s-eficaz/

Comment: Hola Agustin Martinez, bienvenido, Para poder ayudarte, necesitamos tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar), y si recibes errores, indica cuales son. Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: Creo que lo pude hacer, el codigo quizas sea medio basico o escrito de forma tosca: SELECT campo, lote, fecha_s, semilla, 
avg(rendimiento) as promedio,
max(rendimiento) as maximo,
min(rendimiento) as minimo
FROM campos_norte
group by campo, lote, fecha_s, semilla; 
Esta bien? también le agregue los lotes (que son las divisiones dentro del campo).

Comment: También estuve viendo de filtrar por la expresión mayor (>) solo realizando el promedio y los valores no son iguales. En esa consulta la ante ultima linea escribí lo siguiente: WHERE rto_qq_aju > 50. No se como funciona el foro, esta debería ser una nueva pregunta? ¡Muchas gracias a los que se tomaron el tiempo de responder!